# How do I set up String schema with Double or Long attribute in Big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm creating a BigQuery table with a column having string attribute. Unfortunately the message payload is exceeding the recommended size in BigQuery. In current configuration, I can not split the field into multiple columns.

Is there a way to set up String columns as Double or Long to increase the limit ?

I have tried to export the schema though CLI. In BQ documentation only String is defined as valid data type. 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types

Expected Results: is string column having entire message.
Current result: Biqquery service logs:  Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes

Comment: More context needed. BigQuery limitation for Strings is 10MB. I just tested it with a 2MB string without probllems.

Comment: My string values are definitely larger than 10 MB. I have to put entire messages in the columns. Is there a way to set up string fields more than 10 MB ?

Comment: My apologies! I meant the limit is 100MB. I just loaded one to make sure - its length is 99000000 (that's 99MB). BigQuery ingested it without problems.